# Nuxt application is 404 erroring on refresh when deployed to now

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

My nux app is displaying a 404 not found error when I refresh the page. If I navigate through ssr through the nuxt-links routing it works fine. What am i doing wrong?

I am deploying to now.sh using the 'now' command.

I am using slug and my main vue file is _vue.vue to act as a main template for dynamic pages.

```
<template>
<div>
<headerBanner :pagetitle="post[0].title.rendered" :acf_subtitle="post[0].acf.subtitle_text"/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios' 
import headerBanner from '~/components/headerbanner.vue'

export default {

  components: {
      headerBanner
  },

  asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    console.log(`https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=${params.vue}`)
    return axios.get(`https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=${params.vue}`)
    .then((res) => {
      return { post: res.data }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
    })
  },

  layout: 'default'
}


</script>
```

now.json

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "nuxt-static",
    "builds": [
        { "src": "package.json", "use": "@now/static-build" }
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Nuxt.js project",
  "author": "jordan",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "now-build": "nuxt generate"  
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.7.2",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^2.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.4.0",
    "nuxt-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "nuxt-payload-extractor": "^0.0.8",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't deploy a Nuxt app with Now v2. You need to use 1. Nuxt has documentation on this. https://nuxtjs.org/faq/now-deployment#how-to-deploy-with-now-

Comment: @BillCriswell well, you can https://github.com/nuxt/now-builder

Comment: Ah sweet. Wasn't aware of that, just what was in the docs which is what the poster almost seemed to be following.

Answer (score 1):

You are deploying it as static website. Nuxt dont generate routes for dynamic pages by default.

Anyway you could just use nuxt now build. https://github.com/nuxt/now-builder

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/now-builder",
      "config": {}
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/_nuxt/.+", "headers": { "cache-control": "s-maxage=31536000" } },
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Done that and getting 'bad gateway' now.

Comment: @jord49 well, then u did something wrong, check logs